# Proof that $O(n^2 + n + a)$ is a subset of $O(n^2)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

I'm new to the Big-O Notation and couldn't find any question that covers my problem of understanding. From my intuition, it is clear that for $n\rightarrow+\infty$, that $n^2+n+a$ "behaves" like $n^2$, so any function that has an upper bound in the form of $n^2+n+a$ also has an upper bound of the form $n^2$, but the $n_0$ and $c$ will be different.

Unfortunately, I fail to proof formally that this is correct. If somebody could provide a proof using the Big-O definition, I would be glad.

Comment: Step 1: write down the definition of Big-O notation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(n) \in \mathcal O(n^2 +n+a)$ with
$$f(n) \le c_0 (n^2 +n+a)\quad\forall n\ge n_0$$

Now chose $n_1 = \max(a, 2, n_0)$ such that $n_1^2 \ge n_1 +a$. Then
$$f(n) \le c_0 (n^2 + n + a) = c_0 n^2 + c_0 (n+a) \le c_0 n^2 + c_0 n^2 = 2c_0 n^2 \quad\forall n \ge n_1$$
Thus $f(n) \in \mathcal O(n^2)$ for constants $n_1$ and $c_1 := 2c_0$.

More generally you can prove that $f\in\mathcal O(g)$ and $g\in \mathcal O(h)$ implies $f\in\mathcal O(h)$ as well as $\mathcal O(g) = \mathcal O(f + g)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wasn't able to find a $n_1$, but your choice makes sense.

Comment: @Maxbit That is essentially the choice for proving $n+a\in\mathcal O(n^2)$ and then using the more general statement.

Comment: Sorry, I have to ask one more thing: It is clear to me that $n_{1}^2 \ge n_1 + a$. But I'm not really sure about why $n_1 = max(2a, 2, n_0)$. Isn't $n_{1}^2 \ge n_1 + a$ sufficient? Why did you chose the 3 values and why are they necessary?

Comment: You also need $n_1 \ge n_0$ for the first inequality.

Comment: Okay, then we need to chose an $n_1$ such that $n_{1}^2 \ge n_1 + a$ and $n_1 \ge n_0$, but unfortunately I don't see how to get from that to $n_1 = max(2a, 2, n_0)$.

Comment: That‘s just a lazy solution to both. We don‘t need a sharp result here because it doesn‘t matter.

Comment: Ahh, I thought it was a lazy solution, but I'm not able to understand why there is $2a$ instead of $a$, so $n_1 = max(a, 2, n_0)$ From my perspective, with this definition of $n_1$ we know  $n_1 \ge n_0$ and we can say that $a^2 \ge a + a = 2a$ is true for all $a > 1$. Where did I do something wrong? Why is $a$ not sufficient?

Comment: You need $a>2$ for that, but yes.

Comment: Err, sorry, but $2^2 = 4 \ge 2 + 2 = 4$ is true, isn't it? Because $4 \ge 4$? I'm probably not seeing something really simple

Comment: Yep, your choice works as well.